# Chamar function ao manter pressionado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Boa tarde,
Estou tentando fazer uma função para executar uma ação ao manter um item de um lista pressionado pro x minutos, mas não estou achando uma solução para isso. Alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O que já tentou? Mostre o código.

Comment: Qual é a versão do jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$( "#target" ).on({
    mousedown: function() {
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
              foo();
        }, 60000));
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer') );
    }
});
```

Esse 60000 no setTimeout é a quantidade em milisegundos que você quer que ele fique pressionado. No caso se eu quiser que ele pressione por 10 segundos seria:

***10 x 1000 = 10000***

```js
$( "#target" ).on({
    mousedown: function() {
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
              foo();
        }, 2000));
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer') );
    }
});


function foo() {
    alert('Yaay !')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="target">Segure por 2 segundos</button>
```

Comment: Sabia que é possível adicionar os códigos HTML, CSS e JS para serem executados na própria resposta? Veja como nessa [imagem](https://imgur.com/a/TNgvNOR).

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, obrigado pela informação :)

Comment: Muito obrigado Vinicius, era isso q eu precisava.

Comment: +1 pela edição com código executável na resposta.

Comment: Veja o cálculo (10 x 100 = 10000) está errado.

Comment: corrigido @LaércioLopes :) obrigado

Comment: @ViniciusFarias Como fazer isso com javascript puro?